# Is there an easy way to change to a non-root user in Bitbucket Pipelines Docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

[Bitbucket Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) is using Docker containers to executes tasks and by default Docker containers run as root. This is a problem for NPM's lifecycle scripts because NPM tries to downgrade its privileges when it runs scripts.

When executing the `postinstall` script, [NPM throws an error](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3497) that it `cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s)`. The simplest solution is to run npm install with the `--unsafe-perm` flag, but I don't like this approach.

Docker's [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/user) for writing Dockerfiles states that:

> If a service can run without privileges, use USER to change to a
>   non-root user.

When configuring a typical Docker container I would create a new, non-root user and run my npm scripts as this user.

After reading [Pipelines documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/get-started-with-bitbucket-pipelines-792298921.html) I couldn't find any equivalent to Docker's USER command. <s>I might be able to use `useradd`, `chown` and `su` (didn't test that yet) but is there a simpler solution?</s>

Unfortunately adding `useradd`, `chown` and `su` to `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` script section breaks Pipelines and results in failing `repo:push` webhook.

```
image: node:6.2

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/false node
          - chown -R node: /opt/atlassian/bitbucketci/agent/build
          - su -s /bin/sh -c "npm install" node
          - su -s /bin/sh -c "npm run test:coverage --silent" node
```

Pipelines responds with

```
{
  "code": 500,
  "message": "There was an error processing your request. It has been logged (ID <removed>)."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most comfortable solution I've found is to create a non-root user account only if it's not already included in the image and use the [gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu) utility to set it for executed commands.

Pipelines' `build` step is already setting the `chmod 777` on the `$BUILD_DIR` so additional `chown` is not required.

So, to be able to change to a non-root user in Bitbucket Pipelines Docker container you have to:

1. add an additional shell script to your repository that installs the gosu utility (it can also be included directly as a step in Pipelies config)
2. call the `install-gosu.sh` script as the first step in Pipelines config,
3. create a non-root user (checking whether it already exists first) with `id -u {user} &>/dev/null || useradd ...`,
4. use gosu to run commands as a non-root user.

**install-gosu.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

GOSU_VERSION=1.10
GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)"

set -x

apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture | awk -F- '{ print $NF }')" \
&& wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/$GOSU_VERSION/gosu-$dpkgArch" \
&& wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/$GOSU_VERSION/gosu-$dpkgArch.asc" \
&& gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4 \
&& gpg --batch --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc /usr/local/bin/gosu \
&& rm -r "$GNUPGHOME" /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc \
&& chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu \
&& gosu nobody true \
&& apt-get purge -y --auto-remove ca-certificates wget
```

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```
image: node:6

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - bash $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/install-gosu.sh
          - id -u node &>/dev/null || useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/false node
          - gosu node npm install
          - gosu node npm test
```

This can easily be adapted for other languages/users/commands. Just swap the `node` user and `npm` commands to whatever you need.

I've tested this method with `nodejs` and `python` images.

Answer (score 3):

There's two things to address in this question.

---

To run as a non-root user in Bitbucket Pipelines, you can do exactly what you have suggested and use the USER Docker command. The node:6.2 image does not map to a non-root user, so if you would like to do so you can create a new Docker image with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.2

USER foo
```

---

The 500 error you are receiving appears to be an issue with YAML parsing on this line:

```
- chown -R node: /opt/atlassian/bitbucketci/agent/build
```

The ':' is a special character in the YAML format. Indicating a key-value pair. In order to fix this, put the contents on that line inside of quotes instead like this:

```
- "chown -R node: /opt/atlassian/bitbucketci/agent/build"
```

I would also suggest you use the new default environment variable for the build path now. $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR. So change the line to instead be

```
- "chown -R node: $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR"
```

Comment: Question. I keep seeing references to this `/opt/atlassian/bitbucketci/agent/build` in other PipeLines questions. Does anyone know where to find the agent info for the container that is running so i can grab the generated build?

Answer (score 2):

Since the node image already creates a node user (at least in 6.9+), you don't need the `useradd`. It also seems to work well without the chown. In the end, I have a script looking like this - and it appears to be just fine:

```
image: node:7

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - su -s /bin/bash -c "npm install" node
          - su -s /bin/bash -c "npm run build" node
```

Answer (score 0):

In many cases the best way to run any pipeline is not as root.
This is because your end-users, most probably, are not going to use your software as root.

Therefor, the container you are running the pipeline on can be running as non-root by creating your own user during the image build and still make it part of the sudo group in case you need sudo at some point.
I would also recommend adding a password to your user as shown below.
These are the commands for the DockerFile in case you want to stick to Docker.

```
RUN adduser --ingroup sudo userName
RUN echo userName:password | chpasswd
```

Finally you can change user with the following command.

```
USER userName
```

If the last user being used in your DockerFile is ***userName*** then the pipeline will run with that same user.

In order to run sudo commands, I would recommend adding a Repository variable in Bitbucket with the ***userName***'s password and call the sudo command as such:

```
echo $USERNAME_PASSWORD | sudo -S $commandToRun
```